# Training Object Detection without bounding boxes

Tags: tensorflow

I have many high-quality images of specific furniture provided by a museum. Each object is photographed in front of a white screen, so there is only one object per image. We don't have annotations with bounding boxes. The goal is to identify these objects inside photographs where more than one object is depicted.

As input for Tensorflow's Object Recognition API (using the [PET](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/running_pets.md) tutorial as inspiration), we automatically created the bounding boxes by setting it to the whole image by reading it's height and weight. So the input results in one bounding box with one label for each image. The train/val split was done 80/20 for each category individually, of which we have 48.

The used model is *faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_pets.config* (adjusted only num_classes and the *.record files). We continue training with the provided weights from Tensorflow's model zoo using the appropriate weights for COCO.

After 5000 steps, the `TotalLoss` shown by Tensorboard is nearly 0. With some spikes every so often, it stays at slightly above 0 for at least 30,000 steps.

Using the validation set for validating, Tensorboard shows a mAP of 0.13 after 15,000. It doesn't change very much (+/- 0.2) for the next 15,000 steps.
Is this expected? The corpus is very unbalanced, ranging from 130 images per category to only 3. But still, even for the more popular classes, the precision is 0.18. No precision is higher than 0.2.

When extracting the inference graph, the result of detecting the trained categories in images of interiors with more than one object, it looks like it's detecting random boxes, at least it looks like it's somewhat random.

The learning rate schedule from the config file tells me that it'll be decreased after 900,000 and then again after 1,200,000 steps. Is it really necessary to train for this high amount of steps? I am using the pre-trained COCO weights, so it shouldn't need that much time? I'm only training on one GPU.

Answer (score 0):

If you suspect that the neural network is not learning anything, you can try training it on a smaller set. If everything is set up correctly it should be able to overfit and get high precision (but fail to recognize data it hasn't seen)

However, if your goal is simply to identify the type of furniture in the image, I would suggest using a CNN classifier instead of a R-CNN because R-CNN is more focused on localization of the object. I think the newly released Tensorflow Object Detection API is focusing on R-CNN.

Fortunately, image classification without localization is an easier problem to solve, and Tensorflow already has some very nice examples on the [official website](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_recognition)

I am also a little concerned about the amount of data you have. Deep learning requires a large amount of data, but according to what you said, there are sometimes only 3 images for certain categories, which may not be enough even with data augmentation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also have more popular categories. I want an R-CNN because the main goal is to classify the trained objects in a compositional image where more objects are depicted.

Answer (score 0):

If all of your objects are against a white backdrop it should be easy to threshold a grayscaled version of the image into a binary mask then find the bounding box of the resulting mask.

You can use OpenCV to do this, here is a tutorial on the basics of thresholding:
https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html

Likely your mask will be discontinuous in some areas and that could give rise to multiple components. You can address this with morphological filtering:
https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html

Finally, when you are satisfied with the final mask you can find the mask's countours and bounding box:
https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html

These bounding box values can be then be parsed into the appropriate format for the model you wish to train. For the Google Object Detection API, using the PASCAL VOC format seems best.

I'd give some example code here but i'd be best to have an image for this.